# NServiceBus - Could not load file or assembly '' or one of its dependencies

Tags: .net, nservicebus4, nservicebus-sagas

I am working with an .Net Web App that consumes messages from a NServiceBus (v4.7.0) queue. I am getting the following exception:

> 2019-02-20 15:35:13,624 [28] ERROR
>   NServiceBus.Unicast.Transport.TransportReceiver [(null)] - [(null)] -
>   Failed to deserialize message with ID:
>   0942d9eb-126e-4af6-b860-a9f400a3be82
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: An error occurred
>   while attempting to extract logical messages from transport message
>   NServiceBus.TransportMessage ---> System.IO.FileLoadException: Could
>   not load file or assembly 'xpto.Contracts, Version=1.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=6a17a7d57c13b3cf' or one of its
>   dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not
>   match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
>   ---> System.IO.FileLoadException: The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from
>   HRESULT: 0x80131040)    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>   at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean
>   throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly,
>   StackCrawlMarkHandle stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean
>   loadTypeFromPartialName, ObjectHandleOnStack type)    at
>   System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean
>   throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly,
>   StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean
>   loadTypeFromPartialName)    at System.RuntimeType.GetType(String
>   typeName, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean
>   reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)    at
>   System.Type.GetType(String typeName, Boolean throwOnError)    at
>   NServiceBus.Unicast.Messages.MessageMetadataRegistry.GetMessageMetadata(String
>   messageTypeIdentifier) in
>   c:\BuildAgent\work\1b05a2fea6e4cd32\src\NServiceBus.Core\Unicast\Messages\MessageMetadataRegistry.cs:line
>   52    at
>   NServiceBus.Unicast.Messages.ExtractLogicalMessagesBehavior.Extract(TransportMessage
>   physicalMessage) in
>   c:\BuildAgent\work\1b05a2fea6e4cd32\src\NServiceBus.Core\Unicast\Messages\ExtractLogicalMessagesBehavior.cs:line
>   75    at
>   NServiceBus.Unicast.Messages.ExtractLogicalMessagesBehavior.Invoke(ReceivePhysicalMessageContext
>   context, Action next) in
>   c:\BuildAgent\work\1b05a2fea6e4cd32\src\NServiceBus.Core\Unicast\Messages\ExtractLogicalMessagesBehavior.cs:line
>   52    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at
>   NServiceBus.Unicast.Messages.ExtractLogicalMessagesBehavior.Invoke(ReceivePhysicalMessageContext
>   context, Action next) in
>   c:\BuildAgent\work\1b05a2fea6e4cd32\src\NServiceBus.Core\Unicast\Messages\ExtractLogicalMessagesBehavior.cs:line
>   56    at NServiceBus.Pipeline.BehaviorChain`1.Invoke() in
>   c:\BuildAgent\work\1b05a2fea6e4cd32\src\NServiceBus.Core\Pipeline\BehaviorChain.cs:line
>   35    at
>   NServiceBus.Sagas.RemoveIncomingHeadersBehavior.Invoke(ReceivePhysicalMessageContext
>   context, Action next) in
>   c:\BuildAgent\work\1b05a2fea6e4cd32\src\NServiceBus.Core\Sagas\RemoveIncomingHeadersBehavior.cs:line
>   23    at NServiceBus.Pipeline.BehaviorChain`1.Invoke() in
>   c:\BuildAgent\work\1b05a2fea6e4cd32\src\NServiceBus.Core\Pipeline\BehaviorChain.cs:line
>   35    at
>   NServiceBus.Unicast.Behaviors.RaiseMessageReceivedBehavior.Invoke(ReceivePhysicalMessageContext
>   context, Action next) in
>   c:\BuildAgent\work\1b05a2fea6e4cd32\src\NServiceBus.Core\Unicast\Behaviors\RaiseMessageReceivedBehavior.cs:line
>   18    at NServiceBus.Pipeline.BehaviorChain`1.Invoke() in
>   c:\BuildAgent\work\1b05a2fea6e4cd32\src\NServiceBus.Core\Pipeline\BehaviorChain.cs:line
>   35    at
>   NServiceBus.MessageMutator.ApplyIncomingTransportMessageMutatorsBehavior.Invoke(ReceivePhysicalMessageContext
>   context, Action next) in
>   c:\BuildAgent\work\1b05a2fea6e4cd32\src\NServiceBus.Core\MessageMutator\ApplyIncomingTransportMessageMutatorsBehavior.cs:line
>   22    at NServiceBus.Pipeline.BehaviorChain`1.Invoke() in
>   c:\BuildAgent\work\1b05a2fea6e4cd32\src\NServiceBus.Core\Pipeline\BehaviorChain.cs:line
>   35    at
>   NServiceBus.UnitOfWork.UnitOfWorkBehavior.Invoke(ReceivePhysicalMessageContext
>   context, Action next) in
>   c:\BuildAgent\work\1b05a2fea6e4cd32\src\NServiceBus.Core\UnitOfWork\UnitOfWorkBehavior.cs:line
>   34    at NServiceBus.Pipeline.BehaviorChain`1.Invoke() in
>   c:\BuildAgent\work\1b05a2fea6e4cd32\src\NServiceBus.Core\Pipeline\BehaviorChain.cs:line
>   35    at
>   NServiceBus.Unicast.Behaviors.ForwardBehavior.Invoke(ReceivePhysicalMessageContext
>   context, Action next) in
>   c:\BuildAgent\work\1b05a2fea6e4cd32\src\NServiceBus.Core\Unicast\Behaviors\ForwardBehavior.cs:line
>   24    at NServiceBus.Pipeline.BehaviorChain`1.Invoke() in
>   c:\BuildAgent\work\1b05a2fea6e4cd32\src\NServiceBus.Core\Pipeline\BehaviorChain.cs:line
>   35    at
>   NServiceBus.Audit.AuditBehavior.Invoke(ReceivePhysicalMessageContext
>   context, Action next) in
>   c:\BuildAgent\work\1b05a2fea6e4cd32\src\NServiceBus.Core\Audit\AuditBehavior.cs:line
>   17    at NServiceBus.Pipeline.BehaviorChain`1.Invoke() in
>   c:\BuildAgent\work\1b05a2fea6e4cd32\src\NServiceBus.Core\Pipeline\BehaviorChain.cs:line
>   35    at
>   NServiceBus.Unicast.Behaviors.ImpersonateSenderBehavior.Invoke(ReceivePhysicalMessageContext
>   context, Action next) in
>   c:\BuildAgent\work\1b05a2fea6e4cd32\src\NServiceBus.Core\Unicast\Behaviors\ImpersonateSenderBehavior.cs:line
>   37    at NServiceBus.Pipeline.BehaviorChain`1.Invoke() in
>   c:\BuildAgent\work\1b05a2fea6e4cd32\src\NServiceBus.Core\Pipeline\BehaviorChain.cs:line
>   35    at
>   NServiceBus.Unicast.Behaviors.MessageHandlingLoggingBehavior.Invoke(ReceivePhysicalMessageContext
>   context, Action next) in
>   c:\BuildAgent\work\1b05a2fea6e4cd32\src\NServiceBus.Core\Unicast\Behaviors\MessageHandlingLoggingBehavior.cs:line
>   21    at NServiceBus.Pipeline.BehaviorChain`1.Invoke() in
>   c:\BuildAgent\work\1b05a2fea6e4cd32\src\NServiceBus.Core\Pipeline\BehaviorChain.cs:line
>   35    at
>   NServiceBus.Unicast.Behaviors.ChildContainerBehavior.Invoke(ReceivePhysicalMessageContext
>   context, Action next) in
>   c:\BuildAgent\work\1b05a2fea6e4cd32\src\NServiceBus.Core\Unicast\Behaviors\ChildContainerBehavior.cs:line
>   17    at NServiceBus.Pipeline.BehaviorChain`1.Invoke() in
>   c:\BuildAgent\work\1b05a2fea6e4cd32\src\NServiceBus.Core\Pipeline\BehaviorChain.cs:line
>   35    at
>   NServiceBus.Pipeline.PipelineExecutor.InvokeReceivePhysicalMessagePipeline()
>   in
>   c:\BuildAgent\work\1b05a2fea6e4cd32\src\NServiceBus.Core\Pipeline\PipelineExecutor.cs:line
>   44    at
>   NServiceBus.Unicast.UnicastBus.TransportMessageReceived(Object sender,
>   TransportMessageReceivedEventArgs e) in
>   c:\BuildAgent\work\1b05a2fea6e4cd32\src\NServiceBus.Core\Unicast\UnicastBus.cs:line
>   1099    at
>   NServiceBus.Unicast.Transport.TransportReceiver.OnTransportMessageReceived(TransportMessage
>   msg) in
>   c:\BuildAgent\work\1b05a2fea6e4cd32\src\NServiceBus.Core\Unicast\Transport\TransportReceiver.cs:line
>   439    at
>   NServiceBus.Unicast.Transport.TransportReceiver.ProcessMessage(TransportMessage
>   message) in
>   c:\BuildAgent\work\1b05a2fea6e4cd32\src\NServiceBus.Core\Unicast\Transport\TransportReceiver.cs:line
>   356

The funny thing is that I changed the "xpto.Contracts" signature and it no longer has the PublicKeyToken=6a17a7d57c13b3cf', can't find any reference to that key token. Where is this coming from?

Comment: Are you missing a binding redirect?

Comment: Don't think so, there is no local reference to the PublicKeyToken so it sounds like this is coming from Raven Studio but I don't know much about this system